# Installing Linux onto eMMC

Tags: linux, installation

everyone.

I'm new here, and somewhat a noob when it comes to Linux, but here's my situation. A friend had gotten an HP netbook (11-d020) with a 32GB eMMC. Even after getting a 32GB SD for additional storage, she's still frustrated with her space filling up. I'm trying to put Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon instead of Windows to clear up some space (Mint is the first that came to mind as an easy switch for her).

Well, I've installed Linux onto other machines no problem, but this one has me stumped. First, as I go into setting up the disks, the text `Error fsyncing/closing /dev/mmcblk0rpmb: Input/output error` appears. Clicking "Retry" doesn't get me anywhere, so I click "Ignore."

While working on the partitions, I see `/dev/mmcblk0`, presumably the eMMC. There's also `/dev/mmcblk0boot0`, `/dev/mmcblk0boot1`, and `/dev/mmcblk0rpmb`, which I presume are premade partitions on the eMMC. I've considered creating partition tables for these "devices," but I'm afraid this might create another problem. Then there's `/dev/sdb`, the external SD.

I've tried putting /boot onto either, and also trying efi (as well as the `swap` and `/` partitions). However, either the installation says GRUB2 couldn't be installed, or the entire installation will complete but the system will say there's no booting device when I turn it on. I've seen info that Linux might not like eMMC's that had Win8.1 by default, but I'm hoping there's a fix other than creating a LiveUSB, especially since the lack of a USB 3.0 port will make that quite slow as a primary OS.

Some material I've looked at has been over my head, so I apologize if the answer has been posted somewhere. Thanks for any help.

Edit: I'll include some more information. I've been trying to accomplish the installation from a LiveUSB made from Pendrive Linux's Universal USB Installer program. I've been creating the `/`, `/boot`, and `swap` partitions. The error I mentioned where grub fails to install occurs when I tried to create an efi partition.

Comment: First of all "/dev/mmcblk0boot0", "/dev/mmcblk0boot1", and "/dev/mmcblk0rpmb" should not be touched at all. If you aren't doing anything to it but it's the distro installer, then basically it has a bug. /dev/mmcblkN (/dev/mmcblkNpM) is simply like /dev/sdX (/dev/sdXY). `grub-install` in grub 2.02-beta2 can handle the mmcblk namings just fine. so either mint is using an even older release of grub2 (which is insane), or it's a bug of its installer again (well, or your pebkac).

Comment: FYI: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=4e93b9a6abc0d028daf3c8a00cb77b679d8a4df4 the patch is pretty recent btw, so your first issue might be due to the fact that mint is with an old kernel

Comment: Would that create a problem in booting the OS? I thought the rpmb didn't have anything to do with boot configurations. I should mention that I've also tried a few flavors of Puppy, and none of those have worked either. Could I manually install grub outside of Mint's installer? And how would I do that.

Comment: I don't think the issue will cause anything worse than error spamming in your kernel messages.

Comment: I'm honestly not concerned with that as I'm only trying to get a workable Linux installation for my friend who definitely won't be worrying about kernel messages. Perhaps I should also mention that in Mint's installer, I had marked /dev/mmcblk0 and /dev/sdb as the devices marked for bootloader installation, matching the device that I put the /boot or efi partition on.

Comment: I am quite sure you can install grub outside Mint's installer. For example you can switch to another tty or open a terminal if it's some GUI live iso, and then try to run an appropriate `grub-install` command. What should be the exact command depends on whether your want UEFI or BIOS boot (which sort of depends on how the installation medium is booted too), and whether you run it inside a chroot, and maybe also how is the partition layout. You need to at least make sure that the root filesystem and /boot filesystem (if any) are mounted properly somewhere (/mnt, /mnt/boot for example).

Comment: I don't get it. Why is /dev/sdb involved?

Comment: I tried it, thinking that Mint wasn't wanting to go on the eMMC, though it's only an SD.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Tom, for your help. I ended up solving this problem by using Unetbootin to make a LiveUSB with Mint 17.2 (instead of 17.3) and then installed it, and it went smoothly. You're probably right; there must be a bug in the 17.3 installer, or maybe in Pendrive Linux's program.